# cuando intento hacer una petición get con axios en react me sale vacio el array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Cuando intento hacer una paticion get en React me sale vacio el array con los hooks...

```
useEffect(() =>{
    const obtenerLista = async (res) => {    
        await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/inventory")
           .then(res => getProductos(res.data));
        console.log(setProductos)
    }
    obtenerLista()
}, [])
```

El resltado es el siguiente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar como declaras los hooks?

Comment: Podría ser que haya un problema con el endpoint al que le estás haciendo el get. ¿Intentaste copiar y pegar la URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/inventory` a tu navegador para ver si la API está funcionando bien?

Comment: si lo intente y si me sale el contenido

Comment: y como declaro los hooks, son de la siguiente manera  `const [ setProct, getProct ] = useState([])`

Comment: Cuando dices "me sale vacio el array con los hooks" ¿En donde te sale vacío? ¿En el `console.log(setProducts)` que tienes ahí en el ejemplo? Saludos

Comment: si en el `console.log()` y cuando lo quiero imprimir el codigo me sale error

Comment: El setProductos no es una variable, es una función, deberias mandar a imprimir productos

Comment: es cuando sale el error por que no llega nada al hooks

Comment: Muestrame el codigo completo y que hay en la función getProductos porfavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quizás en ese momento donde estas haciendo el console.log aun no tienes la data, prueba mostrándola en otro lado, pon en el return del componente esto

```
return <div>{setProductos && <p>{JSON.stringify(setProductos)}</p>}</div>;
```

y ve si lo muestra, probablemente sea eso